# i am trying to connect my localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress

"Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your wp-config.php else we can't do anything. Also change the title to "Wordpress - Can't connect to MySQL - Connexion refused". Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a good question.

Comment: Let us see config file, if everything right in file, check your firewall inbound rules about 3306 mysql port and mysql user priviliages.

Answer (score 1):

Locate config.inc.php

find this,

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] =
```

if there is localhost change it to 127.0.0.1

Like this

Change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

into

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Save.
Then restart your local server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, OS (Linux/Windows..), you should make sure the mysql/mariadb service is running.

> ps aux | grep mysqld mysql    15202  0.3  8.5 1065616 175388 ?
>   Ssl  Jan16 565:04 /usr/sbin/mysqld

and which port is listening to :

> netstat -tulnp | grep mysqld tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15202/mysqld

Second, make sure the credentials defined in your configuration actually exist an have the proper rights inside mysql

If the mysql/mariadb service is running, you can connect and check : 
from os shell :

> # mysql -u [your_user] -p[your_password]  -D mysql
>
> MariaDB [mysql]> select user from user;

here you should find your user as defined in file "wp-config.php", where wordpress should store mysql connection data.

Examples are from Linux, since I think is the most common, but if you share more on your environment, the answer could be more accurate.